# unable to upload large size(up-to 2GB) files in Microsoft Edge Browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-edge, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo File uploader on **Asp.Net MVC**. 
When I attempt to upload files up to 1.9GB using Win 10 Edge while tab crashes. 
My Edge's version is **41.16299.547.0**
After it crashes, Page automatically **refreshed**. But the upload fails.

I monitored the memory usage (from task manager) during the process. It appears that the upload process ran out of memory.

I repeated the same process with the same file in **FF, Chrome**. The file is uploaded successfully. How to resolve this issue? **Is there any coding stuff required**?

Comment: how you are uploading the data ? are you using any readers ?Are you using multipart formdata ?, IE normally takes the entire data into RAM that is what cause the out of memory issue.  You may have to split your data and send it across if its too large.

Comment: I am using the following link.
[Ref](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/async) .
file format such as zip,rar,pdf files only used to upload. total size is 1.92GB. **MS Edge** only gives crashing issue. Internet Explorer also works fine. why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

For larger file upload, I suggest you could use the [Chunk Upload](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/chunkupload), it will split files into smaller fragments with predefined chunk size and upload them one by one.

Code like this (you could set the chunksize):

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("Chunk_Upload_Save", "Upload")
            .Remove("Chunk_Upload_Remove", "Upload")
            .AutoUpload(true)
            .ChunkSize(1100)
        )
    )
</div>
```

More details about the Chunk upload, please check [this article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/upload/chunk-upload).

Comment: As it says in the above link, This looks like the correct way. I have converted as chunk upload. but, My question is, let me know that why does MS Edge give out of memory issue. As I have been using MS edge as the default browser.

Comment: It seems like a [public issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15099599/), you could also add a comment on that thread. And, I have already reported to MS, will continue to track this issue.